# Change the default chrome download folder webdriver C#

Tags: c#, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

i want to change the default download directory of the chrome. I did go through the different argument listed in the following url
http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

and 

http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/wiki/CapabilitiesAndSwitches

I would like to know how to change the download folder during the run time in chrome web driver C# , 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Thank u for pointing that out , i am not able to get it work

Comment: I'm trying to find the answer to this question as well.  Here si the only page that I've found that has decent documentation on available options but I'm hoping it isn't complete. https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
   namespace UnitTestProject1_webdriver
{

public class ChromeOptionsWithPrefs : ChromeOptions
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> prefs { get; set; }
}

[TestClass]
public class demo
 {
    [TestMethod]
    public void demo1()
    {var options = new ChromeOptionsWithPrefs();
        options.prefs = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "download.default_directory", @"c:\download temp\" }
        };
        RemoteWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"d:\selenium dlls\", options);
    }
 }


}
```

Comment: during run time darling.. you should remove this answer