# Selenium Python Chromedriver Change File Download Path

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, download, selenium-chromedriver

I'm looking for a way to save different files to different locations in python using chromedriver. The code below sets chrome to download to folder_path without pop the download location dialogue first. 
After clicking and downloading one file into folder_path (I skipped pasting this part of code cause I have no issue), I want to download another file into new_folder_path. But the code below gives me AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'Chrome'. Any ideas if I can change download location for Chrome under the same webdriver?

```
folder_path = "C:\\Document"

def give_chrome_option(folder_path):
    chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions() #setup chrome option
    prefs = {"download.default_directory" : folder_path,
           "download.prompt_for_download": False,
           "download.directory_upgrade": True}  #set path
    chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs) #set option
    return chromeOptions
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = give_chrome_option(folder_path)
driver.get(sample_url)
driver.Chrome(chrome_options = give_chrome_option(new_folder_path))
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to re-instantiate WebDriver if you want to download to a different directory. Depending on what exactly do you need to do, a workaround described in the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23897531/1733471) might be suitable for you (download to a temporary directory then move file using `os.rename()`)

Comment: That's an interesting idea. I should be able to achieve the same result. I just have to add another function to allocate files after I load all of them. Another idea I'm looking at is to pass cookie and file url from Selenium to urllib. I'm not familiar with that process but it seems urllib.retrieve can save files to different folder locations. Thank you.